# Deleting comments in VLQ UI doesn't work

Tags: bug, review, user-interface, low-quality-posts

- add a (regular) comment to the post being reviewed
- delete it
- => the "are you sure" window does not appear, the comment disappears
- open the question by the corresponding link, scroll to the post
- => the comment is still there